# What is the circular item that fell off of the returning booster during the CRS-16 mission?

Tags: spacex, launch, falcon-9, reentry, dragon

During reentry of the first stage booster on the Dragon Resupply Mission (CRS-16), there was a ring-looking item that floated away from the booster.

[image]

I would imagine it is some sort of ice debris, but why is it this shape? What else could this possibly be?

You can see the vide [here](https://youtu.be/Esh1jHT9oTA?t=1484). The item appears at 24:44.

Comment: The commentator in the video suggests it's 'frozen condensation' so your guess of ice is very likely

Comment: From a speculative perspective, what do you think it could have fallen from? It is an interesting shape for ice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Current theory seems to be one of the Nitrogen cold gas thrusters had some condensation that was ejected when fired.

There was some concern it might have hit the grid fin that failed, but that seems unlikely at this time.